# What are the differences between a cpdef and a cdef wrapped in a def?

Tags: python, cython

In the Cython docs there is an [example](http://docs.cython.org/en/latest/src/userguide/early_binding_for_speed.html) where they give two ways of writing a C/Python hybrid method. An explicit one with a cdef for fast C access and a wrapper def for access from Python:

```
cdef class Rectangle:
    cdef int x0, y0
    cdef int x1, y1
    def __init__(self, int x0, int y0, int x1, int y1):
        self.x0 = x0; self.y0 = y0; self.x1 = x1; self.y1 = y1
    cdef int _area(self):
        cdef int area
        area = (self.x1 - self.x0) * (self.y1 - self.y0)
        if area < 0:
            area = -area
        return area
    def area(self):
        return self._area()
```

And one using cpdef:

```
cdef class Rectangle:
    cdef int x0, y0
    cdef int x1, y1
    def __init__(self, int x0, int y0, int x1, int y1):
        self.x0 = x0; self.y0 = y0; self.x1 = x1; self.y1 = y1
    cpdef int area(self):
        cdef int area
        area = (self.x1 - self.x0) * (self.y1 - self.y0)
        if area < 0:
            area = -area
        return area
```

I was wondering what the differences are in practical terms.

For example, is either method faster/slower when called from C/Python?

Also, when subclassing/overriding does cpdef offer anything that the other method lacks?

Comment: For one, `cpdef` methods, unlike `def` methods, have return types in their signatures. From a technical point of view, `cpdef` methods introduce less overhead when accessed from Cython, because they do not create a Python call stack frame.

Comment: @EliKorvigo Sorry, I'm a bit confused. Do you mean when accessed from Cython with untyped arguments? Otherwise you'd use `cdef` method, right?

Comment: I don't quite understand, how you've interpreted my message. `cpdef` methods have the same typed signature as `cdef` methods

Comment: @EliKorvigo What I meant is. In your original comment you seem as I understand it to compare `cpdef` to `def`. But when calling from within Cython I would think it more appropriate to compare to the wrapped `cdef` because that is what you would call in the `cdef` wrapped in a `def` scenario. - Unless the arguments (the actual arguments you are passing, not the signature) are for some reason untyped. So I was asking whether that is what you mean.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

chrisb's answer gives you all you need to know, but if you are game for gory details...

But first, the takeaways from the lengthy analysis bellow in a nutshell:

- For free functions, there is not much difference between `cpdef` and rolling it out with `cdef`+`def` performance-wise. The resulting c-code is almost identical.
- For bound methods, `cpdef`-approach can be slightly faster in the presence of inheritance-hierarchies, but nothing to get too excited about.
- Using `cpdef`-syntax has its advantages, as the resulting code is clearer (at least to me) and shorter.

---

**Free functions:**

When we define something silly like:

```
 cpdef do_nothing_cp():
   pass
```

the following happens:

1. a fast c-function is created (in this case it has a cryptic name `__pyx_f_3foo_do_nothing_cp` because my extension is called `foo`, but you actually have only to look for the `f` prefix).
2. a python-function is also created (called `__pyx_pf_3foo_2do_nothing_cp` - prefix `pf`), it does not duplicate the code and call the fast function somewhere on the way.
3. a python-wrapper is created, called `__pyx_pw_3foo_3do_nothing_cp` (prefix `pw`)
4. `do_nothing_cp` method definition is issued, this is what the python-wrapper is needed for, and this is the place where is stored which function should be called when `foo.do_nothing_cp` is invoked.

You can see it in the produced c-code here:

```
 static PyMethodDef __pyx_methods[] = {
  {"do_nothing_cp", (PyCFunction)__pyx_pw_3foo_3do_nothing_cp, METH_NOARGS, 0},
  {0, 0, 0, 0}
};
```

For a `cdef` function, only the first step happens, for a `def`-function only steps 2-4.

Now when we load module `foo` and invoke `foo.do_nothing_cp()` the following happens:

1. The function pointer bound to name `do_nothing_cp` is found, in our case the python-wrapper `pw`-function.
2. `pw`-function is called via function-pointer, and calls the `pf`-function (as C-functionality)
3. `pf`-function calls the fast `f`-function.

What happens if we call `do_nothing_cp` inside the cython-module?

```
def call_do_nothing_cp():
    do_nothing_cp()
```

Clearly, cython doesn't need the python machinery to locate the function in this case - it can directly use the fast `f`-function via a c-function call, bypassing `pw` and `pf` functions.

What happens if we wrap `cdef` function in a `def`-function?

```
cdef _do_nothing():
   pass

def do_nothing():
  _do_nothing()
```

Cython does the following:

1. a fast `_do_nothing`-function is created, corresponding to the  `f`- function above.
2. a `pf`-function for `do_nothing` is created, which calls `_do_nothing` somewhere on the way.
3. a python-wrapper, i.e. `pw` function is created which wraps the `pf`-function
4. the functionality is bound to `foo.do_nothing` via function-pointer to the python-wrapper `pw`-function.

As you can see - not much difference to the `cpdef`-approach.

The `cdef`-functions are just simple c-function, but `def` and `cpdef` function are python-function of the first class - you could do something like this:

```
foo.do_nothing=foo.do_nothing_cp
```

As to performance, we cannot expect much difference here:

```
>>> import foo
>>> %timeit foo.do_nothing_cp
51.6 ns ± 0.437 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000000 loops each)

>>> %timeit foo.do_nothing
51.8 ns ± 0.369 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000000 loops each)
```

If we look at the resulting machine code (`objdump -d foo.so`), we can see that the C-compiler has inlined all calls for the cpdef-version `do_nothing_cp`:

```
 0000000000001340 <__pyx_pw_3foo_3do_nothing_cp>:
    1340:   48 8b 05 91 1c 20 00    mov    0x201c91(%rip),%rax      
    1347:   48 83 00 01             addq   $0x1,(%rax)
    134b:   c3                      retq   
    134c:   0f 1f 40 00             nopl   0x0(%rax)
```

but not for the rolled out `do_nothing` (I must confess, I'm a little bit surprised and don't understand the reasons yet):

```
0000000000001380 <__pyx_pw_3foo_1do_nothing>:
    1380:   53                      push   %rbx
    1381:   48 8b 1d 50 1c 20 00    mov    0x201c50(%rip),%rbx        # 202fd8 <_DYNAMIC+0x208>
    1388:   48 8b 13                mov    (%rbx),%rdx
    138b:   48 85 d2                test   %rdx,%rdx
    138e:   75 0d                   jne    139d <__pyx_pw_3foo_1do_nothing+0x1d>
    1390:   48 8b 43 08             mov    0x8(%rbx),%rax
    1394:   48 89 df                mov    %rbx,%rdi
    1397:   ff 50 30                callq  *0x30(%rax)
    139a:   48 8b 13                mov    (%rbx),%rdx
    139d:   48 83 c2 01             add    $0x1,%rdx
    13a1:   48 89 d8                mov    %rbx,%rax
    13a4:   48 89 13                mov    %rdx,(%rbx)
    13a7:   5b                      pop    %rbx
    13a8:   c3                      retq   
    13a9:   0f 1f 80 00 00 00 00    nopl   0x0(%rax)
```

This could explain, why `cpdef` version is slightly faster, but anyway the difference is nothing compared to the overhead of a python-function-call.

---

**Class-methods:**

The situation is a little bit more complicated for class methods, because of the possible polymorphism. Let's start out with:

```
cdef class A:
   cpdef do_nothing_cp(self):
       pass
```

At first sight, there is not that much difference to the case above:

1. A fast, c-only, `f`-prefix-version of the function is emitted
2. A python (prefix `pf`) version is emitted, which calls the `f`-function
3. A python wrapper (prefix `pw`) wraps the `pf`-version and is used for registration.
4. `do_nothing_cp` is registered as a method of class `A` via `tp_methods`-pointer of the `PyTypeObject`.

As can be seen in the produced c-file:

```
static PyMethodDef __pyx_methods_3foo_A[] = {
      {"do_nothing", (PyCFunction)__pyx_pw_3foo_1A_1do_nothing_cp, METH_NOARGS, 0},
      ...
      {0, 0, 0, 0}
    }; 
.... 
static PyTypeObject __pyx_type_3foo_A = {
 ...
  __pyx_methods_3foo_A, /*tp_methods*/
 ...
};
```

Clearly, the bound version has to have the implicit parameter `self` as an additional argument - but there is more to it: The `f`-function performs a function-dispatch if called not from the corresponding `pf` function, this dispatch looks as follows (I keep only the important parts):

```
static PyObject *__pyx_f_3foo_1A_do_nothing_cp(CYTHON_UNUSED struct __pyx_obj_3foo_A *__pyx_v_self, int __pyx_skip_dispatch) {

  if (unlikely(__pyx_skip_dispatch)) ;//__pyx_skip_dispatch=1 if called from pf-version
  /* Check if overridden in Python */
  else if (look-up if function is overriden in __dict__ of the object)
     use the overriden function
  }
  do the work.
```

Why is it needed? Consider the following extension `foo`:

```
cdef class A:
  cpdef do_nothing_cp(self):
   pass

cdef class B(A):
  cpdef call_do_nothing(self):
    self.do_nothing()
```

What happens when we call `B().call_do_nothing()`?

1. `B-pw-call_do_nothing' is located and called.
2. it calls `B-pf-call_do_nothing`,
3. which calls `B-f-call_do_nothing`,
4. which calls `A-f-do_nothing_cp`, bypassing `pw` and `pf`-versions.

What happens when we add the following class `C`, which overrides the `do_nothing_cp`-function?

```
import foo
def class C(foo.B):
    def do_nothing_cp(self):
        print("I do something!")
```

Now calling `C().call_do_nothing()` leads to:

1. `call_do_nothing' of the`C`-class being located and called which means,`pw-call_do_nothing' of the `B`-class being located and called,
2. which calls `B-pf-call_do_nothing`,
3. which calls `B-f-call_do_nothing`,
4. which calls `A-f-do_nothing` (as we already know!), bypassing `pw` and `pf`-versions.

And now in the 4. step, we need to dispatch the call in `A-f-do_nothing()` in order to get the right `C.do_nothing()` call! Luckily we have this dispatch in the function at hand!

To make it more complicated: what if the class `C` were also a `cdef`-class? The dispatch via `__dict__` would not work,  because cdef-classes don't have `__dict__`?

For the cdef-classes, the polymorphism is implemented similar to C++'s "virtual tables", so in `B.call_do_nothing()` the `f-do_nothing`-function is not called directly but via a pointer, which depends on the class of the object (one can see those "virtual tables" being set up in `__pyx_pymod_exec_XXX`, e.g.  `__pyx_vtable_3foo_B.__pyx_base`). Thus the `__dict__`-dispatch in `A-f-do_nothing()`-function is not needed in case of pure cdef-hierarchy.

---

As to performance, comparing `cpdef` with `cdef`+`def` I get:

```
                          cpdef         def+cdef
 A.do_nothing              107ns         108ns 
 B.call_nothing            109ns         116ns
```

so the difference isn't that large with, if someone, `cpdef` being slightly faster.

Comment: If you wanted to add anything to make it more definitive: how does this all work with `cpdef` class methods (e.g. to make them overrideable)? I suspect it's all pretty similar but it'd be interesting to know which parts get replaced and what the call-chain is for an overridden method. (Entirely your own choice if you want to address this though...)

Comment: @DavidW just stumbled over [this](http://docs.cython.org/en/latest/src/userguide/pyrex_differences.html#cpdef-functions) little nugget in the Cython docs. In the chapter on "Differences between Cython and Pyrex". Seriously, that's precisely where I would have put it - if I wanted to make sure people don't find it.

Answer (score 2):

See docs [here](http://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/tutorial/cdef_classes.html) - for most purposes they are practically the same, cpdef has *slightly* more overhead but plays nicer with inheritance.

> The directive cpdef makes two versions of the method available; one
>   fast for use from Cython and one slower for use from Python. Then:
>
> This does slightly more than providing a python wrapper for a cdef method: unlike a cdef method, a cpdef method
>   is fully overridable by methods and instance attributes in Python
>   subclasses. It adds a little calling overhead compared to a cdef
>   method.

Comment: I've just placed a bounty on this question in case you are interested.