# How are methods in Cython implemented in C?

Tags: c, class, methods, cython

This is probably a question about "C" not "Cython" but I am trying to understand how classes work in cython.

When I write a class in Cython:

```
cdef class Myclass:

    def __init__(self, a1, ...):
        self.attribute1 = a1

    def __cinit__(self, char *ca1,...):
        self.c_attribute1 = Ca1
        ...
```

I understand that it's basically a `struct` **in c**.

But then:

```
cdef muFunction(self):
    do and return something
```

How are the methods private/local to the object? Can then run at C compiled speed?

Thank you and feel free to point and teach me all terms that I might be using wrongly.

Comment: Profile and assess.

Comment: @jxh what do I compare to? to a C implementation? I changed the title. My question is more about how these functions are methods in C.

Comment: You compare the Cython based code with what you think the equivalent C would have been without Cython.

Comment: It's probably worth looking at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28362009/definition-of-def-cdef-and-cpdef-in-cython/41976772#41976772 - almost all of it applies to methods too. They key point is that `cdef` vs `def` is mainly calling convention, but the code inside runs at exactly the same speed. Beyond that you can probably get some understanding by looking at the generated C code (either the annotated html or search for your source lines in the .c)

Comment: @jxh Thank you. I will try and I like the pragmatic approach. I would still be glad if you/someone could give me a hint on how do you make these functions "local" to the struct (am I using the term local correctly?).

Comment: @ead has [a nice answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48879057/4657412) about the fine details of how methods are implemented (which is probably more than you need to know)

Comment: Can't you find the resulting `c` code to examine?  I believe 'compiling' cython has an annotation parameter that creates a `html` file with highlighting.  Because the C code is machine generated it isn't pretty.  There's a lot of boilerplate.